# How to show arraylist in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

I have a question, how to show this array item_detail to AllertDialog?

```
    //Beri keterangan untuk arrayitem detail
    ItemDetail item_detail = new ItemDetail();
    item_detail.setName("Cake");
    item_detail.setItemDescription("");
    item_detail.setPrice("5.000");
    item_detail.setImageNumber(1);
    result.add(item_detail);

    item_detail = new ItemDetail();
    item_detail.setName("Coklat");
    item_detail.setItemDescription("Bulat");
    item_detail.setPrice("5.500");
    item_detail.setImageNumber(2);
    result.add(item_detail);

    item_detail = new ItemDetail();
    item_detail.setName("Purple");
    item_detail.setItemDescription("Cupcake");
    item_detail.setPrice("6.000");
    item_detail.setImageNumber(3);
    result.add(item_detail);

    return result;
}
```

}

this is my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_image);

    ArrayList<ItemDetail> image_detail = GetSearchResult();

    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
    lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_detail));

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position, long id){
            Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
            ItemDetail obj_ItemDetail = (ItemDetail)o;

            new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
            .setIcon(obj_ItemDetail.getImageNumber())
            .setMessage(obj_ItemDetail.getItemDescription())
            .setNegativeButton("Close", null).show();

            Toast.makeText(ListViewImageActivity.this, "Anda Memilih : " + " " + obj_ItemDetail.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });
    }

private ArrayList<ItemDetail> GetSearchResult() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<ItemDetail> result = new ArrayList<ItemDetail>();

    //Beri keterangan untuk arrayitem detail
    ItemDetail item_detail = new ItemDetail();
    item_detail.setName("Cake");
    item_detail.setItemDescription("");
    item_detail.setPrice("5.000");
    item_detail.setImageNumber(1);
    result.add(item_detail);

    item_detail = new ItemDetail();
    item_detail.setName("Coklat");
    item_detail.setItemDescription("Bulat");
    item_detail.setPrice("5.500");
    item_detail.setImageNumber(2);
    result.add(item_detail);

    item_detail = new ItemDetail();
    item_detail.setName("Purple");
    item_detail.setItemDescription("Cupcake");
    item_detail.setPrice("6.000");
    item_detail.setImageNumber(3);
    result.add(item_detail);

    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have one more question how to make the picture show in content area
>   not in icon. can you help me again?
>   So here is your complete code:

XML: (alert_background.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Java Code:**

```
package com.example.stackoflow_alertdialog;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SOF_AlertDialog extends Activity 
{
    ArrayList<ItemDetail> image_detail;
    private int[] images={R.drawable.ball1,R.drawable.ball2,R.drawable.ball5};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sof__alert_dialog);

        image_detail = GetSearchResult();

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter());

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder mAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SOF_AlertDialog.this);

                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_background,null);

                ImageView Content_img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                TextView Content_txt1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView Content_txt2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView Content_txt3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                Content_img.setImageResource(image_detail.get(position).getImageNumber());
                Content_txt1.setText(image_detail.get(position).getName());
                Content_txt2.setText(image_detail.get(position).getItemDescription());
                Content_txt3.setText("Price: "+image_detail.get(position).getPrice());

//              mAlert.setIcon(image_detail.get(position).getImageNumber()).
                mAlert.setTitle(image_detail.get(position).getName()).
                setView(view).
//              setMessage(image_detail.get(position).getItemDescription()+"\nPrice: "+image_detail.get(position).getPrice()).
                setPositiveButton("Buy", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).
                setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).create().show();
            }
         });
       }

    private ArrayList<ItemDetail> GetSearchResult() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<ItemDetail> result = new ArrayList<ItemDetail>();

        //Beri keterangan untuk arrayitem detail
        ItemDetail item_detail = new ItemDetail();
        item_detail.setName("Cake");
        item_detail.setItemDescription("");
        item_detail.setPrice("5.000");
        item_detail.setImageNumber(images[0]);
        result.add(item_detail);

        item_detail = new ItemDetail();
        item_detail.setName("Coklat");
        item_detail.setItemDescription("Bulat");
        item_detail.setPrice("5.500");
        item_detail.setImageNumber(images[1]);
        result.add(item_detail);

        item_detail = new ItemDetail();
        item_detail.setName("Purple");
        item_detail.setItemDescription("Cupcake");
        item_detail.setPrice("6.000");
        item_detail.setImageNumber(images[2]);
        result.add(item_detail);

        return result;
    }

    private class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return image_detail.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
                TextView txtName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView txtDescription = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView txtPrice = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                ImageView img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                txtName.setText(image_detail.get(position).getName());
                txtDescription.setText(image_detail.get(position).getItemDescription());
                txtPrice.setText(image_detail.get(position).getPrice());
                img.setImageResource(image_detail.get(position).getImageNumber());

            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can accept my answer If you think It is useful for you.

Comment: Thank you Sagar, your code works again. i'm sorry for asking you to help me again and i don't know how to return your favor. i'm so grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom adapter and call this:

```
ItemDetailAdapter adapter=new ItemDetailAdapter(this,GetSearchResult());
new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).setAdapter(adapter, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put below code in your project & Put your images in drawable folder according to your requirement. That's it. You are done here:

**Java Code:**

```
public class SOF_AlertDialog extends Activity 
{
    ArrayList<ItemDetail> image_detail;
    private int[] images={R.drawable.ball1,R.drawable.ball2,R.drawable.ball5};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sof__alert_dialog);

        image_detail = GetSearchResult();

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter());

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder mAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SOF_AlertDialog.this);
                mAlert.setIcon(image_detail.get(position).getImageNumber()).
                setTitle(image_detail.get(position).getName()).
                setMessage(image_detail.get(position).getItemDescription()+"\nPrice: "+image_detail.get(position).getPrice()).
                setPositiveButton("Buy", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).
                setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).create().show();
            }
         });
       }

    private ArrayList<ItemDetail> GetSearchResult() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<ItemDetail> result = new ArrayList<ItemDetail>();

        //Beri keterangan untuk arrayitem detail
        ItemDetail item_detail = new ItemDetail();
        item_detail.setName("Cake");
        item_detail.setItemDescription("");
        item_detail.setPrice("5.000");
        item_detail.setImageNumber(images[0]);
        result.add(item_detail);

        item_detail = new ItemDetail();
        item_detail.setName("Coklat");
        item_detail.setItemDescription("Bulat");
        item_detail.setPrice("5.500");
        item_detail.setImageNumber(images[1]);
        result.add(item_detail);

        item_detail = new ItemDetail();
        item_detail.setName("Purple");
        item_detail.setItemDescription("Cupcake");
        item_detail.setPrice("6.000");
        item_detail.setImageNumber(images[2]);
        result.add(item_detail);

        return result;
    }

    private class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return image_detail.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
                TextView txtName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView txtDescription = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView txtPrice = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                ImageView img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                txtName.setText(image_detail.get(position).getName());
                txtDescription.setText(image_detail.get(position).getItemDescription());
                txtPrice.setText(image_detail.get(position).getPrice());
                img.setImageResource(image_detail.get(position).getImageNumber());

            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: hello Sagar, I've tried to code this code but still error?

can you help me again?

Comment: What kind of error are you having? Will you please elaborate?