# Android: Exit application from custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog, exit, dismiss, activity-finish

I created a **custom dialog** for my main activity with two buttons, `Exit` and `Continue`:

```
public class AgeConfirmationDialog extends Dialog {

    public AgeConfirmationDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);    
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setCancelable(false);
        setContentView(R.layout.age_dialog);
        // .....
        // Find the View objects; checkboxes and buttons logic; SharedPreferences
        // .....
    }
    // .....
}
```

This is how the dialog is launched from the MainActivity:

```
AgeConfirmationDialog d = new AgeConfirmationDialog(this);
d.show();
```

This custom dialog pops out every time the main activity is started, and asks for a age confirmation. I don't want the users to close this dialog using the back button, so I added `setCancelable(false)` in the `onCreate` method. The `Continue` button is disabled until a checkbox is checked. If the `Continue` button is pressed, the dialog is dismissed - using `setOnClickListener`.

The problem is that I don't know **how to dismiss that custom dialog AND finish the main activity** when the `Exit` button is pressed.

Is it possible to do this from the `AgeConfirmationDialog` class by setting a `View.OnClickListener` on the `Exit` button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the code to something like this:

```
public class AgeConfirmationDialog extends Dialog {
    Activity mainActivity;

    public AgeConfirmationDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);    
        this.mainActivity = a;
    }

    //in onClick method of finish-button
    public void onFinishClick(View v) {
        mainActivity.finish(); //finish activity
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to dismiss that custom dialog AND finish the main
>   activity when the Exit button is pressed.

Then you just have to put in your ExitButton Click Listener:

```
finish();
```

For example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        }).create().show();
```

Comment: And how exactly could I do this, considering that I have the AgeConfirmationDialog class that extends Dialog?

Comment: Not at all you just have to put my code and do just like I did. You can also see here that how I have implemented xml layout in Alert Dialog. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499100/how-to-show-arraylist-in-alertdialog/21508878#21508878

Answer (score 0):

Do something in your onclicklistener of exit button. Like:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
            startActivity(intent);
```

And your MainActivity do something like:

```
        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
        finish();
        }
```

What you basically do here is going to mainactivity which is your start activity with some key/value extra and check it in your mainactivity through getintent.

This is best process to exit application or you can use it also in logout.

Comment: Thank you! But isn't this somehow slower than Manu's version?

Comment: It restarts your activity... So it is a little slower